# Vb.net read file by line and print lines which contain a specific string

Tags: vb.net

How would I print out every line from a text file that contains a specific string? I have tried something but that didn't work. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should always supply what you tried. And free code writers like  @ViruZX should wait for that as well before posting answers.

Comment: @OneFineDay "Free code writers like me" seem to get downvoted for free labor now, do we?

Comment: First thing, you don't know who did that and maybe it was for the horrible code